# How can I run my own application after another app running in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For example .

My app is a iTunes plugin , I want to launch it after iTunes start-up.

(Now I can run iTunes in my application use AppleScript.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an executable from your application, you can use NSTask class.
To run a plug-in from iTunes, you need to indicate your plug-in to iTunes and iTunes will run your application for you. Thus, you need iTunes Visual plug-ins SDK.